# Interpretation of Julian Date in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, julian-date

I am trying to adjust a code at work, the issue I face is with JAVA script using Eclipse. I cannot understand how Julian Date or Number is there calculated or chosen because I need to adjust it.

Any suggestions on this brainer?

An example would be:

```
jToday=2456324.5
```

Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Java, frankly didn't know there is a difference; I am new at this!

Comment: [Java, JavaScript, Ham and Hamster](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/29/misunderstanding-markup-xhtml-2-comic-strip/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Joda lib to convert Julian days to java date

```
DateTime dt =  new DateTime(DateTimeUtils.fromJulianDay(2456324.5));
```

[Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) 
- number before decimal point represent number of days since noon on January 1, 4713 BC, and after decimal point fraction of the day; For example, the Julian Date for 1.1.2013 UT 0:30:00,  is 2456293.520833

Answer (score 1):

You can use joda-time to convert between a Julian date like the one you have and any other calendar:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_julian.html

You can also use this function:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0506.html